# Next js 13 Script tag blocks scripts: "Error handling response: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "<URL>" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, embed, calendly

I am embedding a Calendly link into my Nextjs 13 projects. In theory everything works fine... however:

- When the link to the Page with the calendar is clicked directly, the page loads with the embed, no problem, no errors.
- When the same link is accessed through the internal site navigation, the Calendly embed won't load, only the rest of the page (no errors in the console either).
- When this same site is refreshed, the embed loads, but I get between 8 and 10 errors in the console, all related to this:

```
Error handling response: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "<URL>" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

In some instances, the origin URL referenced is "https://www.recaptcha.net", in other instances, the origin URL is "https://calendly.com"

The embed in the code looks like this:

```
 <>
  <Script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" />
 </>

<div>some more code here</div>

<div data-url={profile.calendar_embed}></div>
```

I know that this error has to do with the domain where the embed is coming from, and the protocol, hostname and port being used... but I am looking for some guidance on how to fix that...
Any ideas are highly appreciated.
Thank you.